# Usage of "burn" as a form of mockery - How did it start?

Tags: etymology, american-english, social-media

I have come across numerous posts/memes on social media where, considering A,B and C are different people:

1. A posts something seemingly innocuous.
2. B comments on A's post, something either very funny or offensive to A
3. C comments **"BURN!!"** with some ROFL emoticons

Not the best question, but I am just curious why people say "BURN", when they need to mock/insult other people? (according to [UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=burn)).

How did this usage come into existence?

Is this used only in social media? Or is it used in real world conversations as well?

Comment: Perhaps it is related to the act of [flaming](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flame) in response to the post to A by B, and commented on by C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the UD ***[burn](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=burn)*** (as a form of mockery) is an slang expression made popular by the "*[That 70's show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_%2770s_Show)*," which ran from 1998 to 2006:

> - (slang): to disrespect someone (to diss); to make fun of someone; used by a third party after a first party makes fun of a second party. Brought back to life by the ever-popular [That 70's show](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=That%2070%27s%20Show).

Comment: Urban Dictionary is crap

Comment: @Mitch - Crap: http://it.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=crap

Comment: Ooh... burn! Wait...

Comment: All I'm saying is that I think it makes ELU look bad if you're simply quoting UD. I'd hope ELU has better standards than UD.

Comment: @Mitch - UD has been used here before as a source. It is not the most reliable but it works at times. 4K+  upvotes may imply a plausible suggestion. I think it is worth citing in this case.

Comment: UD is a reasonable source for hints as to the existence of a term and possible instances of usage, but is not a good source of official definitions. The quality of writing there is very informal and is often very misleading or wrong. Also, 'burn' does not mean 'to disrespect someone' or 'to make fun of someone'.

Comment: With street slang, UrbanDictionary can be quite the useful reference, but only in regards to understanding the commonality or popularity of a word or phrase. Due to the nature of UD and its design, the legitimacy of its content in terms of actual definitions is rather questionable.

Comment: And I didn't realize this expression was made popular by That 70's Show. I think the expression was popular before it was used on the show, and really an anachronism, since the expression (as far as I recall) wasn't used in the 70's.

Comment: That fact that the usage was **made popular** by that TV show doesn't explain how that usage **came into existence**, which was a part of the question. **Why** was that particular word used for that purpose by whomever was the first to so use it?

Answer (score 3):

According to Wiktionary, the noun [**burn**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burn) has the following meaning (No. 5) that fits in your context:

> (slang) An intense non-physical sting, as left by an **effective insult**.

The above meaning is derived from its No. 1 meaning:

> A physical injury caused by heat, cold, electricity, radiation or
>   caustic chemicals.

Comment: Actually I imagine the burn is from your cheeks flushed in embarrassment or anger rather than from caustic chemicals.

Comment: @Oldcat Yes, it could mean many things. When it is used on the internet, it is just an expression of hatred, contempt and scorn, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The OED (in a 2019 draft addition) references the 1942 *American Thesaurus of Slang*: "Disparaging or sarcastic remark; gibe" Its next earliest quotation is from the film *Clueless* in 1994:

> *Elton*. You've been flirting with me all year. *Cher*. As if! I've
> been trying to help you and Tai get together. *Elton*. What a burn.
> Why would I go with Tai?"

It's also in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burn) ("used chiefly in the phrase *sick burn*") and other dictionaries, so no need to go to *Urban Dictionary*.

The origin seems to relate either to causing pain, causing redness of the cheeks (or backside), or some combination. I can't find any good evidence about this.

Reference: "burn, n.3." OED Online. Oxford University Press, June 2021. Web. 20 August 2021.

Comment: This use of the word is somewhat different, and easier to understand, than what the question is about. In this example, Elton uses the term to characterise something that he himself was subjected to. In the OP's example, C uses the term, as an exclamation, to join in what B has done to A. Granting that there is an analogy between insults/mockery/embarrassment and the physical pain of burns, why is it that *burn*, as used by C, seems to be a device for joining in the mockery, rather than, say, expressing sympathy with A's possible embarrassment?