# Collocation 'bolt upright'

Tags: adverbs, parts-of-speech

What part of speech is the word *'bolt'* in the adverb *'bolt upright'?*

Comment: OED says such ***adverbial*** usages ["similatively"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/similative) *(in a similar manner)* reflect the noun [***bolt***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bolt) *- a shaft or missile designed to be shot from a crossbow or catapult*, where the relevant attribute of the arrow is that it's ***straight***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : The idiom was formed from the now archaic definition listed in the dictionary meaning "suddenly."  I referenced this definition with a link in the answer I posted.

Comment: So is it a noun?

Comment: http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=18749932&egdisplay=open&egs=18754672

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Is similatively " in a similar manner to a simile" ? I.e. Bolt (crossbow ammunition) a noun, being used as an adverb to mean 'straight' with the quality of a simile.  What flexibility  **!**?

Comment: @Hugh: The exact entry in the full (subscription-only) OED is *1. The n. is used **similatively** (cf. snow-white adj. and n., sand-blind adj.) = ‘as a bolt,’ in bolt up (obs.), bolt upright (see upright adj. and n.); whence   bolt-ˈuprightness n.* But rather bizarrely, OED doesn't actually have a listing for the word *similatively*. The closest I could get was my link above to M-W's definition for *similative* as a noun - *something expressing similarity*. Make of that what you will.

Comment: You  need to give a context.  It's different between "I saw him bolt upright" and "He sat bolt upright".

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, it's an adverb.

> [bolt](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bolt--upright?s=t) : ...(adverb) 26. Archaic. with sudden meeting or collision;
>   suddenly.

Wiktionary defines:

> [bolt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bolt): suddenly; straight; unbendingly. e.g. "The soldiers stood
>   bolt upright for inspection."

Comment: In ***bolt** upright* it is indeed an "adverbial/adjectival" usage, but I disagree about the relevance of your ***archaic*** definition. The sense is of "straight" rather than "sudden". How else to explain over 9000 written instances of [was sitting bolt upright?](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+sitting+bolt+upright%22)

Comment: Hi, Benjamin, why not edit your post including the meaning in the OP's context. You could use [this link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bolt) as a reference that says it means not only suddenly but also "straight, unbendingly"

Comment: @Rathony: Your comment is certainly more "constructive" than mine! Benjamin - if you follow that advice I will make a point of reversing my downvote (but I do recognize there's scope for different opinions on this exact point).

Comment: I don't think you forgot what we discussed in the chat room for 2 hours. Let's do it. There is no harm in editing your answer following advice in comments. Do you think I really wanted to do [this edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299065/usage-of-burn-as-a-form-of-mockery-how-did-it-start/299085#299085)? No. Never. :-)

Comment: @Rathony : Done.

Comment: Looks better. I upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

In the let's-sort-out-the-'adverb'-mess approach that linguists at the University of Sussex, for example, advocate it's a 'degree modifier' or more precisely a secondary modifier subclass adjective (in the 'he was sitting bolt upright' usage) modifier. From the [University of Sussex](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/webteam/gateway/file.php?name=essay---parts-of-speech.pdf&site=1):

> **Degree modifier**
>
> A degree modifier modifies an adjective or an adverb. Semantically, a
>   degree modifier expresses the degree to which some quality is present.
>   Here are some frames for degree modifiers:
>
> This is a(n) ___ good book.
>
> She poured the wine ___ carefully.   Examples are *very, so, really,
>   rather, extremely*, and the informal items *kind of* and *sort of*.
>
> (But note the peculiar behaviour of these last two in the first frame:
>   This is kind of a good book.)
>
> Degree modifiers ending in -ly can be constructed with some freedom:
>   amazingly, frightfully, awfully, terrifically, and so on.  Traditional
>   grammarians assigned these things to the class of”adverbs”, but degree
>   modifiers are quite distinct from adverbs in their grammatical
>   behaviour, and most linguists today prefer to recognize them as a
>   distinct class. A few linguists call them “intensifiers”, but this
>   label is inappropriate, since not all these words “intensify” the
>   meaning of the adjective or adverb which is modified.   English degree
>   modifiers have no inflectional or derivational properties.

The number of secondary modifiers not ending in -ly is fairly small, and these are usually categorial polysemes of adjectives

(*stony broke*(!), *dead slow, plain stupid, wide awake* ...; *piping hot* (?), *finger-lickin' good*(?) ...; *stone cold sober*)

but there is the apparent odd exception (*stock still*).

(The comparable *arrow-straight* has obviously developed into a compound adjective.)

[I prefer the term 'secondary modifier' because many of these have distinct semantic content over and above an intensifying (etc) function (*daringly low, dashingly handsome, deceptively spacious, oppressively close* ...; contrast bland old 'very'.]

Answer (score -1):

"Bolt" has several meanings, it can be a special screw mainly used on machines as shown in these [pictures](https://www.google.de/search?q=bolt%20meaning%20screw%2C%20pictures&oq=bolt%20meaning%20screw%2C%20pictures&aqs=chrome..69i57.45972j0j4&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8).

In picture four you see two bolts, one standing upright on its foot and one on its head.

Of course, I am not sure if this interpretation is the correct one. But "bolt upright" can't be explained with "a flash from the sky" nor with
"arrow". "Bolt upright" is a shortened form of "upright like a bolt".

I would say bolt is a noun used as compound element of a two-part adjective or adverb.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the idiom "bolt upright" is using the definition of "bolt" meaning "in an erect or straight-backed position".