# Can I use 'a little' at the end of this sentence?

Tags: adverbs

I know 'a little' can be used as an adverb to modify an adjective as in the sentence:

> I am a little hungry.

However, can I also use 'a little' just like this in this sentence as well?

> I am hungry a little.

Comment: I am hungry a little is not idiomatic even though it wouldn't have a problem getting the meaning across. Contrast "I am very hungry" with "I am hungry very".

Answer (score 1):

In general, adjective-modifiers in English must come before the adjective if they are lexical units. These include:

> very, really, quite, somewhat, slightly, a little/bit, not [at all]

If they are prepositional phrases and are used to modify the adjective (and not the verb), then they usually come after the adjective, such as in:

> helpful **around the house**
>
> confident **in/about himself**
>
> resolute **to/until the end**
>
> known **among/between us**

However, note that adverbs that can modify the entire sentence can often be placed before or after the sentence, or next to the main verb:

> Often the school children can be found playing soccer.
>
> The school children often can be found playing soccer.
>
> The school children can often be found playing soccer.
>
> The school children can be found playing soccer often.

The last variant is less preferred if the adverb would be too far from the main verb.

Comment: If you include prepositional phrases amongst 'adjective-modifiers', your first sentence needs adjusting: 'Friendly and helpful to the nth degree' / 'polite to a fault' .... Though some use the term for the words (usually intercategorial polysemes of adverbs) that modify adjectives, believing that this usage is far removed from verb-modification.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Well those that you mention (and also "to an extreme" and "useful up to a point" and "accurate down to the last letter") could be considered as idiomatic forms rather than ordinary adjective modification, in the sense that "A to a fault" is an idiom that functions as an adjective that must be in predicate position. Personally I consider them as being 'cut from the same cloth' as prepositional phrases in general, which all cannot in general occur in other positions (apparent exceptions like "is in a way useless" in my opinion have "in a way" modifying the verb "is" instead).

Comment: Not unhappy with your alternative analysis until you suggest that _be_ can be 'modified'. Compare '... is useless with regard to preparing for the actual BMAT' where it is obviously not just 'is' that is being qualified.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Your example actually supports my point. I only said that prepositional phrases in general must come after what they modify, and that "is in a way useless" in my opinion should not be parsed as "is { ( in a way ) useless }" but as "{ is ( in a way ) } useless". What I said also implies that your example should be parsed "is { useless ( with regard to ... ) }". A counter-example to my claim would be an unambiguous example of a prepositional phrase **before** what it modifies. I won't be surprised if there are (this is natural language after all), but I think they're rare.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Okay just after posting my comment I realized unusual word order can produce counter-examples: "To the end we will go/stand." But at least it's a systematic alternate syntax.

Comment: Notice that I'm saying that the term 'adjective modifier' is ill-defined. Does it include only single words (really, very, weirdly, plumb, frighteningly ...) or does it also include larger structures (as is the case with 'adverbial' say)? [Scribd](https://www.scribd.com/doc/31648788/Adjective-Modifier) uses the term 'modifier' in the broader sense: 'Modifiers can be a word, a phrase or an entire clause.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I guess when I said "adjective-modifier" I had in mind a lexical unit that has that function. If you've a better term for that please tell me, or if you've a better explanation do post your own answer. I'm a native speaker but have no formal linguistics training.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299092/collocation-bolt-upright/314338#314338), and see what you think of the Univ of Sussex article **suggesting** a new workable POS set. The snags with the term 'degree modifier of adjectives' would be (2) it's a mouthful; (1) it works with _very, really, rather, plumb_ etc but not _weirdly, frighteningly_ etc where added meaning is involved (secondary modifier of adj / adv have been suggested); (3) some people do use the term 'modifier' for phrases etc. I hope you're avoiding 'adverb' for 'very' etc on logical grounds.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Hmm I don't see how that term solves the issue you raise either, unless they also exclude prepositional phrases. However, I like the idea of the general thrust of the suggestion that we could call them by a term that allows them to modify both adjectives and adverbs, since there seems to be a systematic semantic relation such as "frighteningly quick[ly]" (the way in which ... quick[ly] is frightening). Perhaps "qualitative specifier" would best describe this functionality. I avoided "adverb" because it's like a catch-all and doesn't help to pin down its grammatical function.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I still think that prepositional phrases must be dealt with separately, because they can function like noun-modifiers and verb-modifiers but tend to be placed after, which seems to me to be due to prosody since it is easy to parse lexical units as noun-modifiers whereas allowing prepositional phrases in front would put more burden on the recipient. (But this is not true in other languages with more free word order.)

Comment: All I'm saying is that 'adjective-modifiers' needs tightening to 'words used to modify adjectives, such as _very, really, rather, plumb, weirdly_, and _frighteningly_....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I've edited my answer to state precisely what I've described in my comments. Is it acceptable now?

Answer (score -1):

You can but with a small modification. The meaning would be the same.

> I am hungry, a little. Or
>
> I am hungry. A little.

In speech, you need the pause to make it sound idiomatic. Otherwise, as mentioned in the comments, it'd be a bit unidiomatic.

Comment: I can't find any convincing examples of the comma version on the internet, and consider this also to be very unusual to weird.